# Transformer Open-Circuit & Short-Circuit Tests

Tags: transformer, testing

I need to find the losses of a transformer through simulation.
I am measuring voltage, current & power.
I know the method to find the losses but I am unsure if I should use the rms or peak values for the measured voltage & current in the calculations of the losses.
Can someone please advise?

Comment: I'd imagine it depends on whether you want to find the RMS or peak values of the losses.

Comment: Hi! Usually, rms values are used. The formulas, in general, consider the values as rms.

Answer (score 0):

> *but I am unsure if I should use the rms or peak values for the
> measured voltage & current in the calculations of the losses*

To measure power properly you cannot (or should not) compute power by measuring voltage and current independently (RMS or otherwise). You should compute power as instantaneous voltage multiplied by instantaneous current and take the average of that waveform. Examples: -

[image]

All easily done in most simulators.

Comment: I am using the average power calculated from the instantaneous power. As that is an average I'm thinking I should convert the peak values on the ammeter / voltmeter to rms and use those values to calculate the transformer losses. Would you advise that?

Comment: Transformer loss = power loss and, given that you are calculating average power, (as per your comment above) there is no reason to try and calculate it a different way unless you are trying to get an indication of what power factor is @Ah1991